# Route not working properly

Tags: laravel-5

I have two route. First one not working and 2nd working. If I put 2nd route in first then its working and another not working.
Here is my route:

```
Route::any('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
'as'=>'class',]);

Route::any('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@showclass',
'as'=>'class',]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function getclass(Request $request)
    {
        if (Input::has('post_comment'))
        {
            $status=Input::get('post_comment');
            $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
            $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

            $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
            'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'status_id'=>$status
            ]);
            Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
        if(Input::has('status-text'))
        {
            $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
            $rules = [
            'status_text'=>'required|string',
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


            if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
            {
                $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
                if($validator->fails())
                {
                    $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                    $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                    $userStatus = new Status();
                    $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                    $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                    $userStatus -> type = 1;
                    $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $userStatus -> save();
                    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                    return redirect(route('class'));
                }
            }
            else if ($validator->fails())
            {
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
                $userStatus -> type = 2;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();
                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('classroom'));
            }
    }


return view('class',[
'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
]);}
```

Another one

```
 public function showclass(Request $request)
    {
        $randomnumber = rand(50001,1000000);

        $classrooms = new Classrooms();
        $classrooms->class_name = $request['class_name'];
        $classrooms->subject_name = $request['subject_name'];
        $classrooms->section = $request['section'];
        $classrooms->class_code = $randomnumber;
        $classrooms -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $classrooms -> save();
        return view('class', array('class' => Auth::user()) );
    }
```

What Should to do now? i think my tow url is same that is the problem.If i am right then how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `Route::any()`.

As the name suggests, it will accept any request (`POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`) to the `/class` URI and process that with the given controller function.

In your case, when you have this first:

```
Route::any('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
'as'=>'class',]);
```

Any request to to `/class` is just being processed by `getClass`, including your form submission.

And it works fine when you put the other first as that is the first one being used.

Try changing `Route::any()` to the type of request they actually get.

For example, something like this:

```
Route::get('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
'as'=>'class',]);

Route::post('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@showclass',
'as'=>'class',]);
```

** NOTE: you cannot use the same URI (e.g `/class`) for two of the same method types (e.g `GET`) as the first route would always match first and be used.

Comment: i used it but still same problem.

Comment: my new route is: Route::get('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@getclass',
'as'=>'class',]);

Route::post('/class',[
'uses'=> 'classroom@showclass',
'as'=>'class',]); and now my error is Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject11\resources\views\class.blade.php) but data inserted.